# The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available - multi try

Tags: apt, 20.04, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, software-sources

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on my WSL and I am facing no pub key error during `sudo get-apt update`. I went through many questions and everywhere are written almost the same answers like:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <KEY>
```

or

```
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:ownCloud:community/xUbuntu_20.04/Release.key
```

... but nothing works for me.

Full error:

```
W: GPG error: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY <KEY>
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
```

Does anyone have idea what can I do more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you may have tried to manually install Docker Engine on Ubuntu under WSL and missed a step.  You have a few options:

- First, the Docker and Microsoft recommended method for installing Docker in WSL is to use Docker Desktop for Windows.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70936753/11810933) for the reasons why I agree with this.

  If you choose to go this route, remove the Docker repository from your sources to resolve the existing error.  You should be able to do this by removing `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`, assuming you were following the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/).  Otherwise, look in that directory as well as the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` for a reference to the Docker repository, and remove it.

  ```
  sudo apt update
  ```

  At which point it should be successful.
- If you do want to proceed with the manual installation of Docker Engine, you should be able to resolve the error by completing Step 2 of the [installation instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/):

  ```
  sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
  curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
  ```

  Again, that should resolve the `sudo apt update` issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes I was trying to install Docker but after a problems I stopped for now. Solution by removing the docker.list and docker.list.save solved the problem. 
The interesting thing is that second step didn't solve the issue and I remember that I was doing this during installation. Anyway thanks!